# Why tmuxinator zsh complete file is not work?

Tags: zsh, tmux, rbenv, oh-my-zsh, tmuxinator

According to the hint, I download the file

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/master/completion/tmuxinator.zsh

into `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_tmuxinator`(file path), but the autocompletion not work.

Then I source the file like below in `~/.zshrc`, it is also not work.

```
. /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_tmuxinator
```

My config environments are:

- zsh: zsh 5.8 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
- tmuxinator: tmuxinator 2.0.1

And I use `oh-my-zsh` as my zsh environment and rbenv to install tmuxinator.

The fpath environment variable in my system is:

```
/home/run/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git /home/run/.oh-my-zsh/functions /home/run/.oh-my-zsh/completions /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/share/zsh//functions/Calendar /usr/share/zsh//functions/Chpwd /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion/Base /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion/Linux /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion/Unix /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion/X /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion/Zsh /usr/share/zsh//functions/Completion/openSUSE /usr/share/zsh//functions/Exceptions /usr/share/zsh//functions/MIME /usr/share/zsh//functions/Math /usr/share/zsh//functions/Misc /usr/share/zsh//functions/Newuser /usr/share/zsh//functions/Prompts /usr/share/zsh//functions/TCP /usr/share/zsh//functions/VCS_Info /usr/share/zsh//functions/VCS_Info/Backends /usr/share/zsh//functions/Zftp /usr/share/zsh//functions/Zle /etc/zsh_completion.d
```

which includes the directory `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to force rebuild `zcompdump`:

```
rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit
```